# algorithm to find user input length of Palindrome in sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have been learning C++ for a few weeks by reading from a website and after failing a chapter summary quiz I've decided to try out some exercises online.
I am trying for almost a day now and after working out many things eventually I've come to a bottleneck.
In this abbreviated version of the code trying to manually find a user input length of palindrome in a text, it works partially expect for this case:
for example:

User input: length - 3, sequence - 12321:

- The requested palindrome is: 2 3 2 (works and prints as expected)

User input: length - 3, sequence - 13122:

current I: 2   Ivec[i]: 3

current RI: 2   Ivec[ri]: 3
counter: 1

current I: 3   Ivec[i]: 1

^^this line should happen for both cases (when ri = 3 and I = 1, but it only happens at the second time when I reaches 3).

current RI: 1  Ivec[ri]: 1
counter: 2

- "There is no such palindrome."

```cpp
std::cout << "Please enter a length: "; //Palindrome length to search in a vector
    int K;
    std::cin >> K;

    std::cout << "Please enter a sequence:\n\n"; 
    int temp = 0;
    std::cin >> temp;

//function to get length of sequence
//loop to convert sequence to a vector of integers

    bool found(false);
    int counter = 0;
    std::vector<int> cvec;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) 
    {
        for(int ri = length; ri >= 0; --ri)
        {
            if(ivec[i] == ivec[ri] && std::abs(ri - i) <= K) 
            {
                if(ri == i && ivec[ri + 1] != ivec[i - 1])
 // for example: 1 2 3 2 1 << (ri(3),i(2)) ignored but the rest works fine and gets added to cvec
                    ++i;
                else
                {
                    cvec.push_back(ivec[ri]);
                    ++counter;
                    std::cout << "current I: " << i << "\tIvec[i]: " << ivec[i] << '\n'
                    << "current RI: " << ri << "\tIvec[ri]: " << ivec[ri] << '\n' << "counter: " << counter << std::endl;
 // used for testing.
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
            // if counter reach user length of Palindrome
            if(counter == K) 
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
    } 

// if found..
```

Comment: Pick one problem, and try to describe in words what the problem is. Leave the code as an illustration; it should not be the explanation. Also, it would be useful if you could trim the code down to just what is needed to demonstrate your problem. Don't worry about preserving the desired functionality, as you'll take the answer from here and plug it into your real code. See [mre].

Comment: Sorry it was my first time posting a question, thanks!

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't quite get the part with the loop if you may give me an example please

Comment: *"it works partially [except] for one case"* -- please add that case to the question (as simple a case as possible makes debugging easier). The less ambiguity in your question, the more likely you are to get a useful answer. Ideally, your code should not depend on user input (assign values to your variables instead of getting values from `cin`). Also, as you seem to have some diagnostic output (a good step), provide the expected and actual outputs.

Comment: @Baron11 I mean [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/cPfGb5sE8)

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! haven't actually covered iterators yet but you helped me understand. Is there a way to turn this question to a solved one?

Comment: @Baron11 If you work a viable solution and you think others would benefit, by all means post the answer below. Be sure to include well commented code, describe where you went off the rails in your original attempt(s), and how your final solution solves the problem. In short, make it helpful for future readers (which is really what this is all about in the first place).